# Inno Setup how to NOT delete special folder during uninstall

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I'am wondering is it possible to keep my "special" folder on the partition after I uninstall my app? I need to keep some files for possibly next installation and it will be very usefull for me this time. Maybe is there any way to set exact location to uninstall or something like this?

Any ideas?

Comment: What special folder? Your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Use `uninsneveruninstall` flag for this folder/files during the installation.

Comment: @RobeN, it's exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid deletion of installed files/folders during the uninstall process you should use `uninsneveruninstall` flag described in [[Files] section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection).

> uninsneveruninstall
>
> ```
> Never remove the file. This flag can be useful when installing 
> very common shared files that shouldn't be deleted under any circumstances, 
> such as MFC DLLs.
> Note that if this flag is combined with the sharedfile flag, 
> the file will never be deleted at uninstall time but the reference 
> count will still be properly decremented.
> ```